# From CEO Desk/CEO Message

Tags: sharepoint-online, out-of-the-box

I need to show CEO message with picture of the Person, at home page.

Is that possible via OOB feature of SharePoint?

I.e:

[image: Example]

Comment: is it one time activity or you want to change it every day?

Comment: Not every day but yes monthly or quarterly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this with an OOTB announcement list. By default this list got a title column, a multiple lines of text column with rich text so you can add any pictures to the text, and a date column for a expiration date.

Now create a new list view for the list. Go to create view > Standard view. Name it to anything that suits you, and choose to only display the "Body" column.

You could set the view to only display items where the expiration date is not greater then today. Go to the Filter section and set it to "Show items only when the following is true". Set the filter to "Expires" is less than or equal to [Today].

Scroll down to "Tabular View" and uncheck the checkbox. Save the view.

Add the list to the page and then edit the web part. Set it to use the new view you created under "Selected View". Change "Toolbar Type" to "No Toolbar". Click "Apply" and then save the page. If you wanna hide the column name "Body" above the list item, add a script editor the page and add the following CSS. This hides all the columns for the specific webpart.

```
<style type="text/css">
#WebPartWPQX .ms-viewheadertr
 {
  display: none;
  }
</style>
```

In the class #WebPartWPQX, **X** should be a number which you can find by using F12 developer tools ( Press F12 in the browser ) and click on the list to find the web part ID. So it should be WebPartWPQ1 as a example.

This is what the result looks like on a page.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad it did. :)

Comment: There is little more I need to ask. When I am inserting a pic in it, then text either comes below it or above it.  In case if I want to add the text just adjacent to the pic (like above in the example), how would I do that !!

Comment: Ah, when you have an image in the text box and some text, you can click on the image and you then there will be another tab in the ribbon that is called "Image". Click on pthe button "position" and select float - Left or Right. :)

Comment: I am having a little trouble while using these codes, it remove titles of other lists too, on the same page.  Is it possible to make this code to web app specific!!

Comment: You have to use F12 to find the web parts correct id, and target the css by those.. do you know how to use the developer tools?