# Newsfeed webpart with documents

Tags: web-part, newsfeed

I'm searching a web part that would display the latest news with several documents and a picture optionnally. I know that you can share documents in the Sharepoint's newsfeed but i'm searching a custom webpart i could add on a page and display News in it with a shotcut to download documents attached to it. Does it already exists?

And by the way, is there a forum or somwhere i could ask stuff like that? (searching of webparts). So i don't have to spam stackexchange with that kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

A custom list works for this. You don't need anything more than a title column and a multiple lines of text column. I have answered a similar question like this one before with a more detailed answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141908/from-ceo-desk-ceo-message/141910#141910).

You wanna use a rich text multiple lines of text column. Using it, you can easily insert any content that you want and with pictures. You can also upload document directly in the text box (you will still need to choose a location to store them, like a document library).

Clicking on the documents will offer a dialog to the user that asks them if they would like to download them locally.
[image]

Comment: Hi. I don't get it, your download link is linked to the same document for every news? Since the download link is hardcoded. And how does this work? If i add a new item in the list will it show only the latest item added or every items of the list?

Comment: And also, the document should be uploaded by the user that haveright to upload stuff in that list. So i don't know what his document name will be so using the html solution seems strange :<

Comment: Of course you need to change the link to match your environments URL, as well as your documents locations. The above works if your documents resides anywhere else then in the actual list. If the documents will be uploaded to the same list as an attachment, you will need to open the list item to see the attachments, and open them from there.

Comment: When the user that can insert news in the news insert a new item he uploads the documents at the same time. So it won't be possible to get the documents url from there? So i guess the only solution would be to install an existing app with similar features or create one? Do I got it right? Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: Instead of adding the documents as an attachment to the list, you can just upload the file to the multiple lines of test column (you will still need to chose a location for the document) and save it. Clicking it will net you a icon, the file name and a download link from the rich text box.

Comment: It isn't an attachment to the whole list just to the inserted item :P So each item may have or not have documents.

Comment: See my updated answer.