# Announcement list to show only last item

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

Announcement list in SPS2013 to show only the last modified or updated item on the homepage page. Please suggest how it can be achieved and what webpart to use to show the Rich Text / Image enabled content.

Comment: Further update, I`ve followed the following: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141908/from-ceo-desk-ceo-message

However, it shows the Body only. I want to show the Body and Title but in  the following format -

Title: example TExt

Body: Image with Text

Comment: As i answered that question, just add the title field to the view that you are using to display the announcement. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Announcement List and modify the view to set item limit to 1 and sort item in descending order by modified date. Once the view is modified and saved. Go to the homepage, Click on Edit page and add a web-part. Under Web-part section, from list and libraries select your announcement list and select the view from the right hand toolbar where you modified the item limit. Click Apply and Ok.

This will fetch only the latest modified item in your announcement list in the Home page.

Comment: but that is not the solutuon i m after. I want the title n body to appear in deacending order. Pls check my last response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content query web-part for your requirement.

For fetching item: 
You can use orderby "modified column" as descending and set row limit to 1.

For displaying richtext content you can either modified the itemstyle.xsl from stylesheet library or create your own custom xsl.
Here is blog for [how to create custom.xsl](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/displaying-custom-fields-sharepoint-2013-content-query-web-part/)

Comment: thanks for ur response. I 've tried it n getting the internal value for the columns n placement to me seems complex.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the list view webpart that you have added to your homepage and change the view style to "Boxed,no labels" using style section on the view settings page. Order of your columns should be 1. Title 2.Body